# Not able to retrieve both SObjectType (Schema.SObjectType) for ObjectPermissions and (Schema.SObjectField) for SobjectType field on ObjectPermissions

Tags: dynamic-apex

I need to retrieve both SObjectType (Schema.SObjectType) for ObjectPermissions and (Schema.SObjectField) for SobjectType field on ObjectPermissions.

When I try to access `ObjectPermission.sObjectType` and `ObjectPermission.SobjectType` in both cases I receive field token instead of both object token and field token.

Answer (score 0):

To access ObjectPermission object token we need to execute the following code

```
Schema.sObjectType.ObjectPermissions.getSobjectType()
```

To access ObjectPermission SobjectType field token we can use just

```
ObjectPermission.SobjectType
```