# How to get all ObjectPermissions associated with Permission Set

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

According to documentation `ObjectPermissions` represents only enabled object permissions for parent permission set. Permission set license determines which objects are associated with parent permission set but after digging the web I can't find out any possible way to get that information. Is it possible to get all permissionable objects associated with Permission Set?

Example:

Following Query returns only enabled permissions (at least `PermissionsRead = true`).

```sql
    SELECT 
        SObjectType, 
        PermissionsRead, 
        PermissionsCreate, 
        PermissionsEdit, 
        PermissionsDelete, 
        PermissionsViewAllRecords, 
        PermissionsModifyAllRecords 
    FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE Parent.Profile.Name = 'Read Only'
```

Results:

[image]

Records like below isn't stored to avoid redundancy and it is totally understandable.

[image]

I need to find that missing records or at least SObjectType names somehow.
I hope it is clear enough.

I stumbled upon an article from Bill Appleton (CTO at Metazoa) about [The Sparse Profile Problem](https://medium.com/inside-the-salesforce-ecosystem/discover-the-new-world-of-profile-management-ba87a33007af#8469) and I wonder how they determined which of the negative values needs to be added by hand.

Comment: please use [edit] and give an example of what you are looking for

Comment: Question updated @cropredy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are actually asking "how do I find all the objects for which the Permission Set doesn't have access?" As you pointed out, `ObjectPermissions` won't return objects on which the Permission Set has absolutely nothing enabled. Consequently, in Apex, you will need to collect all objects by using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, query and loop through the `ObjectPermissions` to get accessible objects, and remove the current object from the collection of all objects so by the end you are left with only disabled objects.

Be aware that `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` returns all kinds of different system objects, so you'll probably want to somehow filter down which objects you want to check access on before adding to `disabledObjects`.

Code:

```
// Get collection of all sObjects
Set<String> disabledObjects = new Set<String>();
for (String objName : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().keySet()) {
    disabledObjects.add(objName);
    System.debug('Sobject Label Name: ' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().getLabel() );   
}
// Get enabled objects from Permission Set
List<ObjectPermissions> permissions = [SELECT 
        SObjectType, 
        PermissionsRead, 
        PermissionsCreate, 
        PermissionsEdit, 
        PermissionsDelete, 
        PermissionsViewAllRecords, 
        PermissionsModifyAllRecords 
    FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE Parent.Profile.Name = 'Read Only'];
// Remove enabled object from disabled objects collection
for (ObjectPermissions op : permissions) {
    disabledObjects.remove(op.SObjectType);
}
```

Comment: Filter 'Somehow' worries me the most. Here it is an idea how to get all permissionable objects https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255567/how-do-i-find-list-of-all-permissionable-objects but get list in context with current User and some objects are missing.

Comment: I agree it's a tricky one. For another project, I initially tried to figure out User-interactable standard objects by doing similar things to that post you linked to, but realized there were some many edge cases that it was just easier to hardcode the standard objects I cared about and only get custom objects dynamically. Since standard objects change infrequently and only during major Salesforce releases, I think that's a good enough strategy.